# How to spawn multiple enemies in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

So im trying to make a game where the character should dodge enemies which are randomly spawned from above. The problem is, I dont know how to make the Random values different without instanciating another class, which I dont want to do. Also, with Screen.fill(), the enemies wont show up since they're being overlapped by the colour every frame, and if I dont use Screen.fill(), my character would leave a trail everytime it moves. Any Suggestions?

```
import random

pygame.init()
Running = True
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

player_img = pygame.image.load('/Users/kevinhadinata/Downloads/ufo.png')
player_updated = pygame.transform.scale(player_img,(60,60))

enemy_list = []
enemy_img = pygame.image.load('/Users/kevinhadinata/Downloads/alien.png')
SPAWNENEMY = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(SPAWNENEMY,1000)

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ypos = 540
        self.xpos = 325
        self.height = 60
        self.width = 60
        self.playerUpdated = player_updated
    def create_player(self):
        Playerss = pygame.Rect(self.xpos,self.ypos,self.height,self.width)
        pygame.draw.ellipse(Screen, (0, 0, 0), Playerss)
        Screen.blit(player_updated, (Playerss.x, Playerss.y))

sizee = random.randint(10,40)
randomX = random.randint(0,700)

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self):
            self.xval = random.randint(0,700)
            self.size = random.randint(10,40)
    def create_enemy(self):
        Enemy = pygame.Rect(self.xval, 0, self.size,self.size)
        #enemy_updated = pygame.transform.scale(enemy_img,(self.size,self.size))
        enemy_list.append(Enemy)
        pygame.draw.ellipse(Screen,(255,255,0),Enemy)

Player = Player()
Enemys = Enemy()

while Running:
    Screen.fill((0,0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                Player.xpos -= 20
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                Player.xpos += 20
        if event.type == SPAWNENEMY:
            Enemys.create_enemy()

    Player.create_player()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Are you saying you are getting non-random numbers each time you call `random.randint()` during a game?  Or are you wondering why you always get the same pattern on each run of the game?   If it is actually the second, you need to learn how to 'seed' the random number generator when you start the game.  It's in the documentation for `random`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a list of enemies and iterate the list in the main loop to draw each enemy. Use `randint` to randomly place the enemies.

Try this code:

```
import random, pygame

pygame.init()
Running = True
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

player_img = pygame.image.load('/Users/kevinhadinata/Downloads/ufo.png')
player_updated = pygame.transform.scale(player_img,(60,60))

enemy_list = []
enemy_img = pygame.image.load('/Users/kevinhadinata/Downloads/alien.png')
SPAWNENEMY = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(SPAWNENEMY,1000)

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ypos = 540
        self.xpos = 325
        self.height = 60
        self.width = 60
        self.playerUpdated = player_updated
    def create_player(self):
        self.Playerss = pygame.Rect(self.xpos,self.ypos,self.height,self.width)
        pygame.draw.ellipse(Screen, (0, 0, 0), self.Playerss)
        Screen.blit(player_updated, (self.Playerss.x, self.Playerss.y))
        
    def draw(self):  # draw player
        Screen.blit(player_updated, (self.xpos,self.ypos))

sizee = random.randint(10,40)
randomX = random.randint(0,700)

class Enemys:
    def __init__(self):
            #self.xval = random.randint(0,700)
            self.size = random.randint(10,40)
    def create_enemy(self):
        Enemy = pygame.Rect(random.randint(100,700), 0, self.size,self.size)
        #enemy_updated = pygame.transform.scale(enemy_img,(self.size,self.size))
        enemy_list.append(Enemy)
        pygame.draw.ellipse(Screen,(255,255,0),Enemy)
        
    def draw(self):  # draw all enemies
        for e in enemy_list:
            pygame.draw.ellipse(Screen,(255,255,0),e)
            

Player = Player()  # player object
Enemys = Enemys()  # collection of enemies
Player.create_player()

while Running:
    Screen.fill((0,0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                Player.xpos -= 20
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                Player.xpos += 20
        if event.type == SPAWNENEMY:
            Enemys.create_enemy()

    Player.draw()  # draw player
    Enemys.draw()  # draw all enemies
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: thanks man, it worked! also taught me something new.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea to not instantiate a new enemy, because just recycling it back to the top of the screen is enough.  This amounts to simply changing the size & x,y.

Some of your code is occluding the `Enemy` class name with an `Enemy` variable name.  I've changed this variable name to `new_enemy`.

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.recycle()   # set the position & size initially

    def recycle( self ):
        # start or re-start an enemy position
        self.size = random.randint(10,40)
        self.xval = random.randint(0,700)
        self.yval = -self.size              # off the screen-top
        self.rect = pygame.Rect( self.xval, self.yval, self.size, self.size )

    def draw( self, screen ):
        pygame.draw.ellipse( screen, (255,255,0), self.rect )

    def create_enemy(self):
        global enemy_list
        new_enemy = Enemy()               # create a new Enemy
        enemy_list.append( new_enemy )    # add it to the list
```

Then in your main loop, you can `recycle()` any Enemy that goes off-screen.

```
[...]    # in main loop

# draw all the enemies, and re-position any enemies that moved off the screen
for enemy in enemy_list:
    enemy.draw( screen )
    if ( enemy.ypos > 600 ):          # TODO - don't use a fixed size
        enemy.recycle()               # move back to top
```

The drawing an spawning code was mixed-up, I have re-arranged this into a separate `.draw()` function.  Using this solves the problem with clearing the screen too.  Each frame, the code clears the screen, then repaints all the items.